# Duplicate class error: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I've been trying to run my app but it gets an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Flow found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormat found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormatPattern found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.RegExp found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Subst found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
     Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-annotations-java5-21.0.1 (org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1)
```

This is my build.gradle(Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.avs.app"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11'
    implementation 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.5.8'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Looking at the build error, I guess it has something to do with "implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1'"

Build.gradle(app):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Thu Mar 12 17:34:37 PST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

So should I remove the "jetbrains-annotations" line from the build.gradle?
I think removing it will cause errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well like I thought, the solution was removing a single line from build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:21.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this recently.

Noticing that you have

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

which is the cause of this issue.

For solution/workaround, please see this specific comment:

https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/861#issuecomment-872582819